# Odoo12-Accounting Payment

Tags: payment, odoo-12, accounting, journal

I have an invoice with 500USD after that I have the journal entry with 500USD. While I'm doing payment I can add the amount to 800USD so on odoo it will give an option to **keep open**   or **Mark As fully paid**. So I'm choosing the **keep open** option So as per this case odoo has to keep the invoice in an open state with 300USD remaining amount but why it should change the state to pay with the same invoice amount?

So anyone can suggest the functional thing with this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right this is the default functionality of the Odoo and it is extremely cool thing in Odoo because Odoo is managing **`outstanding payments`** of our customer very effectively.

**Important Point**

> If there is an invoice of 500USD and I registered 800USD yes it is
> right thing to close the invoice 500USD because customer has paid it.
> But what about the remaining 300USD. Odoo has cool feature to manage
> outstanding payments. Here you can see in attached image.

I've an invoice of **125USD** and I registered **200USD** *(200-125=65USD)* then see how Odoo manage it for my important customer.

[image]

Comment: yes,! it uses the outstanding credit on the next invoice.